# Replace duplicate values of first column with character "

Tags: unix, awk, solaris

Sample input:

```
a:g:h:e:f:n
a:u:r:t:w:r
a:g:r:o:p:q
d:h:t:y:r:o
d:n:t:s:d:f
d:g:h:u:i:m:
d:s:e:r:t:y
n:m:k:s:t:r
n:r:t:y:w:g
```

Expected output:

```
a:g:h:e:f:n
":u:r:t:w:r
":g:r:o:p:q
d:h:t:y:r:o
":n:t:s:d:f
":g:h:u:i:m:
":s:e:r:t:y
n:m:k:s:t:r
":r:t:y:w:g
```

Replace the first column duplicates with " until a different value is found. This is something i found close to, but replacement is across the file:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(x<27&&$i=="old"){x++;sub("old","new",$i)}}}1' input_file
```

Comment: please also add what you've tried to solve this..

Comment: awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(x<27&&$i=="old"){x++;sub("old","new",$i)}}}1'  input_file             -> this is something i found close to, but replacement is across the file

Comment: is the input always sorted by first column as shown in the sample?

Comment: @Sundeep yes confined to first column only

Comment: `"` as the replacement value is an odd choice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following(Since OP mentioned that o.s is Sun os so use `nawk`).

```
nawk -v var="\"" '
 BEGIN{
   FS=OFS=":"
   }
 {
   $1=++a[$1]>1?var:$1
 }
 1
' Input_file
```

Since you are on Sun o.s using `nawk` in above code. This code will NOT depend on order of first field irrespective of order of it, this should work.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}{t=$1;if($1==p)$1="\"";p=t}1' file
```

Output:

```
a:g:h:e:f:n
":u:r:t:w:r
":g:r:o:p:q
d:h:t:y:r:o
":n:t:s:d:f
":g:h:u:i:m:
":s:e:r:t:y
n:m:k:s:t:r
":r:t:y:w:g
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=":"     # field delimiters
}
{
    t=$1           # 1st field to tmp
    if($1==p)      # if current equals previous
        $1="\""    # replace with "
    p=t            # previous form tmp
}1' file           # output
```

**Update**: Using `sub`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{t=$1;if($1==p)sub(/^[^:]*/,"\"");p=t}1' file
```

Comment: i have solaris box where OFS under awk doesn't work

Comment: If it doesn't work, are you always bound to use space as output delimiter?

Comment: @JamesBrown, I got it sir, he is on sun is where we need to use nawk, looks like mine code worked for him.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yeah, ++ for that. I'm still amazed why OFS wouldn't work. Too bad I trashed my trusty old Sun 5.